# Coroutines - holds resources/threads after timeout/cancellation

Tags: spring-boot, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I would like to to handle method `socketChannel.connectInternal()` with defined timeout. After the timeout is reached the processing of the method should be interrupted and exception handled.
I would like to use kotlinx coroutines for that. This snippet of code works just fine and truly the timeout works as expected:

```
override suspend fun send(message: SocketMessage<T>): SocketMessage<T> {
        val socketChannel = socketChannelFactory
            .createSocketChannel(senderProperties)
        return try {
            socketChannel
                .let {
                    connectWithTimeout(it, senderProperties.connectionTimeout)
                    it.send(message.toBytes())
                    message.fromBytes(it.receive())
                }
        } finally {
            socketChannel.destroy()
        }
    }

    private suspend fun connectWithTimeout(
        socketChannel: SocketChannel,
        timeout: Duration
    ) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async(MDCContext()) {
            socketChannel.connectInternal()
        }.let {
            try {
                withTimeout(timeout) {
                    it.await()
                }
            } catch (e: TimeoutCancellationException) {
                throw ConnectionException(
                    "Connection timeout [${senderProperties.connectionTimeout.toMillis()}]ms.", e
                )
            } catch (e: UnresolvedAddressException) {
                throw ConnectionException("Unable to open connection on given socket address.", e)
            } finally {
                it.cancel()
            }
        }
    }
```

**SocketChannel**:

```
override suspend fun connectInternal() {
        with(senderConfiguration) {
            logger.debug {
                "Using ${this@PlainSocketChannel.javaClass.simpleName}, " +
                    "SocketTimeout [${socketTimeout.toMillis()}]ms, SSL [${ssl.enabled}]."
            }
        }

        socket =  io.ktor.network.sockets.aSocket(SelectorManager(Dispatchers.IO)).tcp()
            .connect(InetSocketAddress(senderConfiguration.ipAddress!!, senderConfiguration.port!!)) {
                if (senderConfiguration.socketTimeout.toMillis() > 0) {
                    socketTimeout = senderConfiguration.socketTimeout.toMillis()
                }
                keepAlive = senderConfiguration.keepAlive
            }

        inputChannel = (socket as Socket).openReadChannel()
        outputChannel = (socket as Socket).openWriteChannel(autoFlush = true)

        logger.debug { "[${javaClass.simpleName}#${senderConfiguration.id}] connection opened." }
    }


override fun destroy() {
        log.debug { "Closing SocketChannel and its I/O streams." }
        inputChannel?.cancel()
        outputChannel?.close()
        socket?.close()
    }
```

**BUT** we noticed that if the timeout happens -> the application itself is permanently slowed down and the performance is getting worse exponentially with another timeouts. Before this "coroutine change" the performance used to be just fine.

I noticed that the slowing down is connected with creating of new coroutines for new transaction flow. It takes seconds to start a coroutine after the performance is "destroyed" by the timeouts. Also JVM Monitoring shows that JVM still holds all the threads and never releases them even no traffic for a long time. Only application restart solves the problem.

I tried to use "async" & "launch", cancel and no-cancel the coroutine in the finally block.
Also I have try{..}finally{..} that cleans the resources - closes the communication,...

Also tried the `withTimeout(...)` without the `async` and `await` but it does not work as expected - the timeout is not working.

Could you provide some advice, please? Thank you :)

**UPDATE**
The method has been changed to the one I consider as the issue - `connectInternal()` or the Socket itself?? -> the communication is non-persistent & there has to be created new socket per request...
I removed all coroutines and timeouts and left just this shared one - and the performance is destroyed when the connection timeout is reached a lot of times. If this coroutine is removed as well - the performance is great but we need this timeout :(

Comment: I think for us to really be able to tell what the performance issue is, we need to see what `process()` looks like. You mention resources being held but we need to see if it cooperates with coroutine cancellation in a way that releases resources. It probably needs to have `try/finally` in it and it of course needs to be a suspend function that cooperates with cancellation.

Comment: I agree with Tenfour04, if `process(context)` is blocking, it doesn't cooperate with cancellation. So using `withContext(IO)` and `withTimeout` around it may give you the illusion you are cancelling work, but you just stop waiting for it - the work keeps going (and thus leaks)

Comment: Thank you, I made an update. I broke the code into parts and found out part of code that causes the issue. - `connectWithTimeout()` and the socket itself. The part with the timeout handling is almost the same.

Comment: Side note, it is an antipattern to be, from within a suspend function, creating a CoroutineScope and starting a separate coroutine that is not a child coroutine, because you are forfeiting structured concurrency.  In this case you don't even need a separate coroutine (child or not). You can replace `CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).async(MDCContext()) { /*...*/ }.let` with `withContext(MDCContext())` and move the content of the former `async` into your `withTimeout` block. The `finally` block is unnecessary. Dispatchers.IO is also unnecessary if `process()` is suspending/non-blocking.

Comment: Yeah, thanks for it, I try to make better in the future :) Anyway this probably won't be the solution. Is it possible that the `io.ktor.network.sockets.aSocket` could be the problem? I mean the `ktor` library itself?

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**

- After some time I found out what the problem was. The `io.ktor.network.selector.SelectorManager` **has to be closed** as well in the destroy method because it holds resources infinitely long in case the opening connection process has not been completed.